# How to set up Parse Server with MongoDB via CloudFormation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, aws-cloudformation

I want to deploy ParseServer with MongoDB via CloudFOrmation in AWS, a comment in an Amazon [post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3LNEWJS45OYA9/Setting-up-Parse-Server-and-MongoDB-on-AWS-using-CloudFormation) says that they are using an out to date version of instance running Node.js. I changed in the "SolutionStackName" to the newest but I got this in the event log:

```
2016-07-29  Status  Type    Logical ID  Status reason
14:02:38 UTC-0500   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate    DevEBConfigTemplate Resource creation cancelled
14:02:37 UTC-0500   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion   ParseAppVersion Resource creation cancelled
14:02:37 UTC-0500   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::IAM::Role  MongoDBHostRole Resource creation cancelled
14:02:37 UTC-0500   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::InternetGateway   InternetGateway Resource creation cancelled
14:02:37 UTC-0500   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::IAM::Role  WebAppRole  Resource creation cancelled
14:02:35 UTC-0500   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate    NonDevEBConfigTemplate  No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.8 running Node.js' found.
14:02:34 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate    DevEBConfigTemplate 
14:02:34 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate    NonDevEBConfigTemplate  
14:02:34 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion   ParseAppVersion 
14:02:30 UTC-0500   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application  WebAppElasticBeanstalkApp   
14:02:30 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  WebAppRole  Resource creation Initiated
14:02:29 UTC-0500   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle    MongoDBWaitHandle01 
14:02:29 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::InternetGateway   InternetGateway Resource creation Initiated
14:02:29 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  MongoDBHostRole Resource creation Initiated
14:02:29 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::VPC   MyVPC   
14:02:29 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application  WebAppElasticBeanstalkApp   Resource creation Initiated
14:02:28 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::InternetGateway   InternetGateway 
14:02:28 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle    MongoDBWaitHandle01 Resource creation Initiated
14:02:28 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  MongoDBHostRole 
14:02:28 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application  WebAppElasticBeanstalkApp   
14:02:28 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  WebAppRole  
14:02:28 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle    MongoDBWaitHandle01 
14:02:21 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  ParseBackend    User Initiated
```

I just don't know what to do. There is other options but I think this is the best, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: did you read the whole comment? :-D it explains what you should do... your log says you are using the Linux v2.0.8 but you should use the latest one, so something like v2.1.1

Comment: Yep, sorry. I just have changed the machine version in one line of the template, but it's Ok now :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS constantly updates its Elastic Beanstalk solution stacks and makes its old stacks obsolete, so you will need to change your solution stack string to the currently-supported version. See the [Supported Platforms (Node.js)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.nodejs) page for the latest supported solution stack name. This is currently (as of 7/30/2016) `64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.3 running Node.js`, and will likely change again in the future.

Comment: My fault, I needed to change the version of the machine in 3 parts of the template